# Regex to filter floating points

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following string:

```
I bought 70 apples for $15.45, 2 cars for 23.000 each
```

I am in search of a regex that can return the following result:

```
I bought {NUMBER:70} apples for ${NUMBER:15.45}, {NUMBER:2} cars for 
{NUMBER:23.000} each
```

I believe the range I would like to filter is a floiting point with (max) 6 digits. I don't know if this would have to be specified.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is your sentence going to always be `I bought {NUMBER} apples for ${NUMBER}.{NUMBER}, {NUMBER} cars for {NUMBER}.{NUMBER} each`?

Comment: So you want ***someone else*** to write ***your*** regex for you? If so, try some regex tutorials and come back with a question about code that you've been unable to make work to your specifications. `$SO !== 'write me a regex site'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$text = preg_replace("((?<!{NUMBER:)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(?!}))","{NUMBER:$1}",$text);
```

This will do what you asked, but also includes a check to ensure that the number hasn't already been put in a `{NUMBER:#}` container ;)

Without the check:

```
$text = preg_replace("([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)","{NUMBER:$0}",$text);
```

Comment: It doesn't work entirely: in "13.45 and $600 bar {7} and {8}" it doesn't catch 7 and 8. An if you make 70 out of it: "Dat foo 13.45 and $600 bar {70} and {8}", it returns {{NUMBER:7}0}. I believe this due to the check you built in - but such a check is not necessary :-) Could you update the regex so it also matches the example here? You're helping me out with my (economics) thesis (i need to do some text analyzing but it's not part of my studies so i'm having a hard time) - your help is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work? "No matching ending delimiter" - so I added ")": preg_replace("([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)","{NUMBER:$0}",$text); but now it doesn't return anything when used on, for instance $text = "Dat foo 13.45 and $600 bar {70} and {8}"?

Comment: Hmm... Added the `)`, and it's working for me. Remember to assign the result back to your variable.

Comment: Yes, you are right - me in a hurry assigned it back to $ext instead of $text. One more question: it now returns (as expected) {{NUMBER:70}}. This was a flaw in my requirements. Is it possible to ignore anything that is between {brackets}. So that the output would be: "Dat foo {NUMBER:13.45} and ${NUMBER:600} bar {70} and {8}" -- only when it is between curly brackets { and }, specifically. Or does this require an additional step apart from this regex?

Comment: Hmm.. that'd be a bit more complicated. I'm afraid I'm not good enough with the more complicated regexes, so you may be better off only checking one side for a brace. In that case, you can use `([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?!}))`.

Comment: Thanks, I might post it in a new post if I can't figure it out. Thanks for helping me out this far!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one: http://regexr.com?2vvpq

`[0-9]+\.[0-9]{0,6}`

Comment: The `\.` needs to be optional: `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{0,6})?`

Comment: And yours doesn't match `70` or `2`.

Answer (score 0):

This expression will solve your problem:

```
([\d.$])*
```

Comment: \d means digits; . will match point; $ will match dollar sign